# How to get sum of objects' properties

Tags: angularjs

I have a function, which adds/removes a new input field on click. Each field has its own ng-model fam.age. And the function calculate the premium, which depends on the age. The result of the function is an array of objects like this:

```
[
   {
      "id":"fam1",
      "age":2,
      "btaccident":0.79,
      "btdisability":0.13,
      "btdeath":0.18,
      "premium":5
   },
   {
      "id":"fam2",
      "age":3,
      "btaccident":0.79,
      "btdisability":0.13,
      "btdeath":0.18,
      "premium":5
   }
]
```

The number of objects depends on how many times the add button will be clicked.

How can I get the sum of 'premium' of each array's object in the VIEW?

I have tried as fallows:

```
$scope.totalFamily = 0;

    $scope.getTotalPremium = function () {
      for (var i=0; i<$scope.familyMembers.length; i++) {
          $scope.totalFamily += $scope.familyMembers[i].premium;
      }  
    };
```

Comment: What you have tried for this. ?

Comment: @Ved I have added my solution in the to the original post.

Comment: Please check my or @sajeetharan answer.

Comment: @Ved @ sajeetharan Thank you! I works great

Comment: Nice. you got your solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use angular.forEach(),

```
  $scope.sum = function(){
    var total = 0;
     angular.forEach($scope.data,function(key,value){
       total+=key.premium;
     })
    return total;
    }
```

**DEMO**

```js
var app= angular.module("MyApp", []);

app.controller("MyController", function($scope) {
    $scope.data =  [
   {
      "id":"fam1",
      "age":2,
      "btaccident":0.79,
      "btdisability":0.13,
      "btdeath":0.18,
      "premium":5
   },
   {
      "id":"fam2",
      "age":3,
      "btaccident":0.79,
      "btdisability":0.13,
      "btdeath":0.18,
      "premium":5
   }
];

$scope.sum = function(){
var total = 0;
 angular.forEach($scope.data,function(key,value){
   total+=key.premium;
 })
return total;
}
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.14/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MyController">
    
    <h1> sum is : {{sum()}}</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using any library like Underscore or Lodash, use `forEach` maethod to loop through object.

```
 var obj = [{"id":"fam1","age":2,"btaccident":0.79,"btdisability":0.13,"btdeath":0.18, "premium": 5},{"id":"fam2","age":3,"btaccident":0.79,"btdisability":0.13,"btdeath":0.18, "premium": 5}];
    var sum = 0;

    obj.forEach(function(val){sum = sum+val.premium})
```